# How can I use the R parallel package to detect / use multiple cores on the Amazon web services (AWS)

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, parallel-processing

I am using R Studio on Amazon web services [(details)](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/running-r-on-aws/), using a m4.2xlarge configuration. I want to use the 'idefix' package to generate an efficient discrete choice experiment (DCE) design [(specifically the CEA algorithm)](https://rdrr.io/cran/idefix/man/CEA.html). The idefix package uses R's 'parallel' package to do this [(parallel package)](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf).

When I try to detect how many cores I have access to, I get the result 1, where I should have 8:

> library(parallel);
>   ncores = detectCores(all.tests = TRUE);
>   print(ncores);
>   [1] 1

I want ncores to equal 8

How can I get access to the extra cores on my AWS instance to use the parallel functionality?

// Edit: Resolved. The issue was with setting up the AWS instance. I needed to create a new one and explicitly tell it how many cores to run.

Comment: That's the correct (and best) command. I'm not an expert on AWS, but my next guess would be to verify via your console and/or payments that they are actually giving your multiple cores.

Comment: A hack, assuming that `/proc` is visible, could be `length(grep("^processor", readLines("/proc/cpuinfo")))`, though I think that's just physical processors.

Comment: @r2evans I just ran that line and am still getting 1 as an answer

Comment: > length(grep("^processor", readLines("/proc/cpuinfo")))
[1] 1

Comment: Okay, to me that means that the operating system is only aware of one physical processor. This further suggests it is a problem with the VM configuration and not with R or your understanding of parallel.

Comment: @r2evans - yep I solved the issue. Creating a new instance on AWS and explicitly telling it how many cores to run worked. Thanks for your help!